# Maximum call stack size exceeded error on Safari

Tags: firebase, next.js, safari

I'm getting `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error when using Next.js for fetching data from firebase in Next.js. I'm pretty sure that is not a bad code optimization because it's a very simple fetch and it only happens on Safari based browsers, in Chrome based browsers it works just fine with the same conditions.

I tried optimizing the code calling just once the data instead of putting a listener, using `useMemo` and `useCallback` but it is just not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Github issue that suggests that the issue happens on Next.js version 12.3.1 and downgrading to 12.3.0 would fix the issue.

I had the version 12.3.1 so I tried downgrading and it works, but it also works if you upgrade to version 13.

Not sure why the issue is being caused and why it affects only to Safari based browsers but [here is the github issue I mentioned](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6720)

Hope this helps someone else :)